# How to do android connect to MySQL database with php page code?

Tags: php, android, mysql, eclipse

I want to connect MySQL database and it didn't work
I tried this code:

```
public void loginPost(View view){
  String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
  String password = passwordField.getText().toString();


  try{


  String link="http://mwssong.esy.es/android/Login.php";
  String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
  data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

  URL url = new URL(link);
  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 

  conn.setDoOutput(true); 
  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 

  wr.write( data ); 
  wr.flush(); 

  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line = null;

  // Read Server Response
  while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
  {
     sb.append(line);
     break;
  } 

  if(sb.toString()=="admin")
      new AdminScreen();          
  else if(sb.toString()=="Customer")
  {

      Intent myIntent(view.getContext(),AdminScreen.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
  }
  else
      status.setText(sb);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
      status.setText("Exception:   " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

}

but it's always gave me in status filed  Exception null
and Intent doesn't work, Eclipse refuse this instructions at all with no solve suggested:

```
      Intent myIntent(view.getContext(),AdminScreen.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
```

and php code is:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('mysql.hostinger.ae','u641845309_ur','q1p0w2o9','u641845309_song');
// username and password sent from Form and protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']); 
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

$sql="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE UName='$username' and Password='$password'";
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);  

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($result)
{ 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


// Redirecting To Other Page
if(strtolower($username)=='admin') 
echo  "Admin"; 
else 
echo  "Customer"; 
  }
}
else 
{
echo  "Your Login Name or Password is invalid"; 
}


?>
```

Comment: This code does not connect to a mysql database, it connects to a php page.

Comment: sorry, I forgot the php code:
this's it:

Comment: I put it in the post

Answer (score 0):

> `mysqli_query`
>
> > returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
> >     EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
> >     other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

so in this case (SELECT query) you should use `mysqli_num_rows`to know the number of records in the result if the number is zero then your SELECT query returns no record which implies no such username and password
like this :

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
  //code executed when username and password are found
} 
else {
  //code executed when no such username and password 
}
```

Comment: add Log.i("response",sb.toString) and tell me of the result

Comment: The text "Exception null "  appears in :
  catch(Exception e){
      status.setText("Exception:   " + e.getMessage());
  }

Comment: check the state of the http connection add this   int code = conn.getResponseCode(); add it after openConnection()

Comment: also you should add setDoInput(true)

Comment: getResponseCode require casting!!

Comment: but still  "Exception null "

Comment: this method returns int it should not requier casting please provide me with its result